# I cant see new android project on Eclipse and i install everything right

Tags: android, eclipse

i did everytihng right and install sdk and jdk for eclips android but create new project doesnt still apear what shoud i do some says eclips doesn't support android anymore is that right?[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKOuh.png)

Answer (score 2):

You must use [Android Studio as official IDE to develop Android Applications](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html), if you are trying to import a project from Android Studio to Eclipse, you will have problems because the projects in Android Studio are configured with Gradle!

I suggest to you [migrate from Eclipse to Android Studio.](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/migrate.html)